# Kitchen setup for US appliances in Europe/India

Tags: usa, india

I am relocating to India from US and taking all the appliances along. I understand that a lot of appliances can go toast due to voltage support as India/Europe has 230v range and US appliances work at 110-120v range. For tvs i can get a separate adapter, but how will it work for kitchen where i would need multiple appliances to be plugged in. 
Basically, is there a smarter way to support multiple power points at 110v range which might be located at different locations.

No TV, I am looking for solution for appliances like instant pot and ninja blender :)

Comment: In most cases, you'll probably be better off selling your US appliances in the US, and buying new or second-hand at your destination, rather than dealing with shipping them, buying adapters, etc.